# Does dist-upgrade upgrade my Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 14.10?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

First, sorry for the silly question. I did some googling, but still not quite sure the answer.

I **dont** want to upgrade my ubuntu to 14.10 because its **not** LTS. However, i want to do some upgrades other than the OS.

Is it safe to use `dist-upgrade`?

I know `dist-upgrade` will upgrade the `kernel`, does it means it will also upgrade the ubuntu version?

Comment: yes, dist-upgrade does not upgrade your OS to the next version. to do so you run a command **sudo do-release-upgrade** to upgrade to the next version

Comment: @OluDoug- That is wrong, see man apt-get. - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/apt-get.8.html "dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade,
           also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions
           of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and
           it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the
           expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade
           command may therefore remove some packages. "

Comment: Please kindly help me : http://askubuntu.com/questions/546363/software-updater-software-updates-not-working-on-14-04-lts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dist-upgrade` should not upgrade the Ubuntu release, only keep you within the same release and upgrade those components that may require removal of some other packages, as explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/226213/283721)

The command to upgrade the version of Ubuntu is `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: He would probably need to invoke `do-release-upgrade -d` or edit /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades to upgrade from LTS to non-LTS release. Just `do-release-upgrade` shouldn't do it by default.

Comment: @DamnTerminal i want to keep my LTS. dist-upgrade is enough, right?

Comment: @BlazeTama `apt-get dist-upgrade` is fine. What I wanted to add is that `do-release-upgrade` shouldn't upgrade your system to 14.10 either, it should only upgrade once the next LTS release is out.

Comment: @DamnTerminal Thanks a lot. I see your point. Surely i will use do-release-upgrade for the next LTS :)

Comment: Please kindly help me : http://askubuntu.com/questions/546363/software-updater-software-updates-not-working-on-14-04-lts