# How to Update Software Updater

Tags: updates

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver). When I launch software updater from the launcher it does not connect to the server to download updates. It always posts "Try again." I always check network settings & I am connected. If I click ok after and try it again, it downloads the updates - so how do I fix this issue? I have tried to delete it just to reinstall it but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Read this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546363/software-updater-software-updates-not-working?rq=1) in case, this worked for other people...

I resume it for you:

try this...

```
sudo rm -rvf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade
```

And then you can reboot your computer, the message you should take back from software updater is your software is already updated.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Why the shutdown instead of reboot? But more importantly, why reboot at all?

Comment: I always shut down my computer after major changes because sometimes reboot is somehow messy... anyway is something I am used to do... but read the link...

Comment: Well, unless you're updating the kernel a reboot here looks unnecessary...  actually even updating the kernel might not need a reboot. At most for desktop settings, maybe just a log out & login again. (even the answer you referenced says reboot's unnecessary)

Comment: You are right, I'll edit my answer...